# Вложенный в словарь список из одного элемента - словаря

Tags: python, словари

Есть словарь:

```
z = { 'a': 1, 's': [{'d': 2, 'f': 3}]}
```

как изящнее обратится к вложенному словарю не разделяя список?

мой вариант -

```
for i in z['s'][0]['d']:
    if z['s'][0]['d'] == 'd':
          s + 1
```

а учитывая что надо проверить все элементы и длину ветвей получается 50 строк вложенных циклов

Comment: В смысле разделяя? Вы так назвали обращение по индексу? Так-то, обращаться к словарю можно так: `z['s'][0]`, и далее уже к ключам словаря: `z['s'][0]['d']`.

Comment: ммм, я не очень точно сформулировал вопрос, там структура сложнее , по две по три вложенных ветви с неизвестным числом компонентов итоговых, хотелось бы пройтись по ним циклом но получается какоет убожество.  скорее нечто вроде этого передают  z = { 'a': 1, 's': [{'d': [{'d': 2, 'f': 3}], 'f': [{'d': 2, 'f': 3}]}]}

Answer (score 5):

Когда нужно перебрать сложную многоуровневую структуру, в которого неизвестно количество уровней вложенности, лучше использовать рекурсию.

Для примера, берем такую структуру:

```
z = {
    'a': 1,
    's': [
        {
            'd': 2,
            'f': 3
        },
        {
            'd': 3,
            'f': 3
        },
        {
            'f': 3
        }
    ],
    'b': {
        'd': 5,
        'f': {
            'd': 1,
        }
    }
}
```

И, для примера, я придумал задачу: подсчитать сумму значения по ключу. В структуре данных я знаю, что среди контейнеров есть только `dict` и `list`.

И по алгоритму мы делаем следующее: проверяем текущий объект, если это словарь, получаем у него список пар – ключ/значение, а у значения проверяем что, если он контейнер, тогда это значение помещаем в функцию, иначе проверяем по ключу, если совпадает – плюсуем к сумме. Если текущий объект список, то у него не может быть ключа, но среди его значений могут быть контейнеры, которые мы проверим в рекурсии:

```
def get_sum_by_key(obj, key):
    val_sum = 0

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                val_sum += get_sum_by_key(v, key)
            elif k == key:
                val_sum += v

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for v in obj:
            val_sum += get_sum_by_key(v, key)

    return val_sum

print(get_sum_by_key(z, 'd'))  # сумма 11
print(get_sum_by_key(z, 'f'))  # сумма 9
```